# How to fetch record while using multiple where condition in date column in mysql

Tags: mysql

I have a table(cookie_log) in which i have a multiple entries of every user on different dates.So i have to fetch only those users whose entry is common in all the dates with **authenticate** where condition for one column.

I have a table structure like that:-

table name **cookie_log**

```
.......................................................
 cl_id   user_id    comment            datetime
.......................................................
   1     101       authenticate    2018-11-28 15:37:08
   2     102       loggedin        2018-11-28 15:37:08
   3     103       authenticate    2018-11-28 15:37:08
   4     101       authenticate    2018-11-29 15:37:08
```

In this record i have to get those user who have authenticate on both the 
date **2018-11-28** and **2018-11-29**.I want this output

```
   .................................
     cl_id   user_id    comment      
    ................................
       1     101       authenticate
```

I have tried below query but not getting my output which i want.

```
SELECT cookie_log.`cl_id`,cookie_log.`user_id` FROM `cookie_log`
where `comment`='login once authenticated' and (`datetime` like '%2018-11-28%') 
and (`datetime` like '%2018-11-29%')
```

Comment: you have to understand that the where clause is applied to _one row at a time_. It's impossible for a single row to meet both those date conditions.

Comment: Even without that, none of your rows contain the comment either, so until you remove or change that clause, nothing will ever match.

Comment: Use conditional aggregation filtering using `HAVING` clause. Do a `GROUP BY` on `user_id`

Comment: Also, it is weird that you are using LIKE '%..%' on a datetime field, instead of proper datetime functions. Even LIKE'..%' will do the job in your case, with an added advantage of utilizing indexing (if defined)

Comment: @madhur can you please write the query.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One possible way is to use `HAVING` clause to conditionally filter out:

```
SELECT user_id
FROM cookie_log
WHERE comment = 'authenticate' AND 
      DATE(datetime) IN ('2018-11-28', '2018-11-29')
GROUP BY user_id 
HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT DATE(datetime)) = 2  -- equal to number of dates to filter upon
```